# How many Xbox/Microsoft accounts can share their games on a single Xbox Series console?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

My Xbox Series console is set as my home console in my main Microsoft/Xbox account, which has lots of games. My sister signs into her own Xbox/Microsoft account on the same console and plays the games that I have the license for.

Now my question is, if she owns and buys games in her own Microsoft/Xbox account, can I play those games as well?

Can 2 people (Xbox/Microsoft accounts) set the same Xbox Series console as their home consoles so that they can share games with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two people can set their console as their home console. Any accounts that are on the xbox can set that console as their home console and can all share their games! In addition to just owned games, you also share xbox live gold subscriptions and game pass subscriptions. Here are instructions on the Microsoft site on how to check/set your [home console](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/console/my-home-xbox).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is completely normal to do, and is absolutely possible. I do it all the time; I live with 3 siblings and my parents, and we all have our Microsoft accounts linked to our Series X. We all play each other's games. You might want to ask support, though.